# I've been testing with two id's and second id doesnt do anything

Tags: html, css

```css
 body {
      background-color:olive;
    }
    #container{
      background-color:;
      display:flex;
    }

    #container > a {
      
      background-color:chocolate;
      margin:5px;
      padding:7px;
      border-radius:10px;
    }
    

    #item-2 {

    }
    #item-4{
      margin-left:auto;
    }

    #bonus {

      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
  <div id="container">
    <a id="item-1 bonus" href="#">Information</a>
    <a id="item-2 bonus" href="#">Contacts</a>
    <a id="item-3 bonus" href="#">Media</a>
    <a id="item-4" href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Hello, could anyone tlel me why doesnt "bonus" class apply background-color:red ? Is there a rule where you can't put two id's or something? Some clarification would be really useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70579/8252164)

Read this regarding HTML attribute `id`.

You can instead use a `class` attribute for having multiple class names on a single element. `id` can't be used like that.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a valid `id`. You can use `class` instead of `id`. Also, update your style for `bonus` to following for getting the right specificity. For details refer to [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)

```css
body {
      background-color:olive;
    }
    #container{
      background-color:;
      display:flex;
    }

    #container > a {
      
      background-color:chocolate;
      margin:5px;
      padding:7px;
      border-radius:10px;
    }
    

    #item-2 {

    }
    #item-4{
      margin-left:auto;
    }

    #container > a.bonus {

      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
  <div id="container">
    <a id="item-1" class="bonus" href="#">Information</a>
    <a id="item-2" class="bonus" href="#">Contacts</a>
    <a id="item-3" class="bonus" href="#">Media</a>
    <a id="item-4" href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
      background-color:olive;
    }
    .container{
      background-color:;
      display:flex;
    }

    .container > a {
      margin:5px;
      padding:7px;
      border-radius:10px;
    }
    
    .link {
      background-color: chocolate;
    }
    

    .item-2 {

    }
    .item-4{
      margin-left:auto;
    }

    .bonus {

      background-color:red;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<nav>
  <div class="container">
    <a class="item-1 bonus link" href="#">Information</a>
    <a class="item-2 bonus link" href="#">Contacts</a>
    <a class="item-3 bonus link" href="#">Media</a>
    <a class="item-4 bonus link" href="#">Logout</a>
</div>
</nav>
</body>
```

I advise you to always use class instead of id (read on this topic: https://dev.to/claireparker/reasons-not-to-use-ids-in-css-4ni4).

Note that I removed the background-color: chocolate property, because the .container > a selector is stronger than the bonus.